# how to use python to get all mysql instances that do not have a specific tag?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to set up an alarm system that will send out emails if some instances do not have a alarm. But for some of the testing instances I do not want them to include so I will put a 'NoAlarms' tag in it. I want to add this feature in my existed python script.

This is basically what I have now.

```
from RDSFunctions import GetListRDSEndpoints
from RDSFunctions import GetListRDSIdentifiers
from boto.ec2.cloudwatch import CloudWatchConnection
from SMTPMail import SendSMTPMail
from boto import ec2
lst_instances = GetListRDSIdentifiers(accesskey, secretkey)
lst_expected_alarms = []
for inst in lst_instances:
    if "relprac" not in inst.lower():
        lst_expected_alarms.append(inst + ' - ' + 'CPUUtilization')
```

Since we are using RDS for these instances not EC2, what should I do to find all instances that do not have the 'NoAlarms' tag?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
import boto.ec2

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("your_region", accesskey, secretkey)

lst_instances = conn.get_only_instances() #gets all instances

for instance in lst_instances:

    if instance.tags['NoAlarms']: #tags are a dictionary ie.['Name': 'NoAlarms']
        pass
    else:
        #add alarms
```